# Is it possible to delete a pasteboard that was originally labeled persistent?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm trying to understand the limitations of the `persistent` property for `UIPasteboard`. Once a user creates a pasteboard with `pasteboard.persistent = YES`, is there any way to remove the pasteboard? From reading the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html) it seems that the pasteboard can't be terminated once it's created...Can someone confirm or reject this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method from `UIPasteboard`:

```
+ (void)removePasteboardWithName:(NSString *)pasteboardName
```

should help you out. Yes, of course you can delete them - they are designed to be accessed and modified by other apps on the iPhone. Persistent only means they will survive a reboot.